# Oracle stored procedure doesn't take complete value of parameter from C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have this procedure in an Oracle package

```
procedure SELECTCPT
(
    IdeAseg  VARCHAR2,
    CodTrata  VARCHAR2,
    FecOcurr DATE,
    msj_error  out varchar2
)
```

And I send it values like this from C#:

```
OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand();
com.CommandText = "PR_SINIESTRO_EN_VERDE.SELECTCPT";
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Connection = con;

com.Parameters.Add("IdeAseg", OracleDbType.Varchar2,50).Value = "62340003";
com.Parameters.Add("CodTrata", OracleDbType.Varchar2,50).Value = "9932";
com.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("FecOcurr", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = "22/01/16";

com.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("msj_error", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 200)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But for some reason the procedure doesn't see the full value `62340003` and only takes `6234`

Is there a way in the procedure to make it use the complete value?

Comment: What character set is being used by the database? Try executing `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET'` and see what it returns. Also - there appears to be a semi-colon missing from the `com.Parameters.Add("IdeAseg"...` line.

Comment: Executed SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' got this = WE8ISO8859P15

Comment: It certainly appears that the parameter `IdeASeg` should have the value `62340003`. If you add the following to your stored procedure, what gets written to the file? `DECLARE aFile UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; BEGIN aFile := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('/', 'test_file.out', 'w'); UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(aFile, 'IdeASeg=''' || IdeASeg || '''', TRUE); UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(aFIle); END;`? You may need to change the directory specified in the `FOPEN` call to something valid for your database.

Comment: Is there any reason you are creating a new OracleParameter for the second two parameters and not for the first?

Comment: no real reason, you think that may be the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't take long to test it?  It could be getting confused as there are two different parameter types being sent into Oracle.  From what I know about Oracle it can be pretty fussy!